# Failing to register with domainname asterisk from local LAN

Tags: registration, sip, asterisk, lan, domain-name

I am using a local asterisk server on a machine behind a router. The asterisk-server has a fixed local IP and the routers external IP is registered with dyndns and can be resolved from outside my network.

1) I am able to register a SIP client with the server from outside my LAN using the domain name mydomain@dyndns.com

2) I am able to register a SIP client with the server from inside my LAN using the local fixed IP address of the asterisk server

3) Howver, I can't register from inside my LAN using the domain name. As a consequence, I need to change registration settings on my mobile SIP client every time I leave my house (or come back home).

I have tried multiple variations and permutations of parameters in sip.conf (localnet, externhost, nat, domain) but fail to get it right (or find a simple explanation what to do in such a basic scenario). Could anybody please help me with the parameters for my sip.conf? Many thanks in advance...

Comment: I should add, that port forwarding is set properly (as I can register from the outside world using mydomain@dyndns.com) and that the asterisk shows a cryptic notice when setting sip debug on:

Comment: NOTICE[20879]: chan_sip.c:14503 check_auth: Correct auth, but based on stale nonce received from '<sip:username@mydomain.dyndns.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue related to your router. When you use external domain from inside lan, path of packet is different and router's firewall(or sip-alg algorithm) can work different.

You choices are

1. Change router. Simplest way.
2. If router have linux/openwrt inside - fix firewall
3. If router have linux/openwrt inside - change dns server to give local ip for requests from inside network.
4. if router support SIP-ALG - try turn that off.
5. Use softphone with more then 1 sip record(for example zoiper free version).

Comment: Thank you. You are correct with respect to the router problem: It happened after my internet provider updated, without my knowledge, the firmware of my router (!!!) - from a security perspective, this is quite scary! The technical term is, as I found out: Nat-reflection. I could solve the problem by entering a static hostname in my router. This will work only for one domain name - but that is fine with me.